# Helmholtz equation superposition

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

In my course we solved the Helmholtz equation in a closed box: $\Delta p =-k^2p$.
The solutions of this problem and the eigenvalues $k$ are given by:
$$p_{k_xk_yk_z}=\cos\left(\frac{m\pi x}{L_x}\right)\cos\left(\frac{n\pi y}{L_y}\right)\cos\left(\frac{l\pi z}{L_z}\right)$$
I understand everthing until now.

Now it is stated that the general solution is given by
$$\sum_{m,n,l}a_{mnl}\cos\left(\frac{m\pi x}{L_x}\right)\cos\left(\frac{n\pi y}{L_y}\right)\cos\left(\frac{l\pi z}{L_z}\right)$$

Why is this true? I can't figure out how this general solution is a solution of the Helmholtz equation:
Let: $a_{111}p_{111}+a_{112}p_{112}=p$

Then clearly $$\Delta p=\Delta(p_{111}+p_{112}+...)=-k_{111}^2p_{111}-k_{112}^2p_{112}\neq-k^2p$$

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Let $p_1$ and $p_2$ be solutions of the Helmholtz equation (which is linear, which implies superposition of solutions) and let $a_1$ and $a_2$ be constants. Then

$$p = a_1p_1 +a_2p_2$$

can be plugged into the differential equation

$$\Delta p +k^2 p=a_1\Delta p_1+a_2\Delta p_2+a_1k^2p_1+a_2k^2p_2=a_1\left[\Delta p_1 +k^2p_1\right]+a_2\left[\Delta p_2 +k^2p_2\right].$$

As $p_1$ and $p_2$ are solutions of the Helmhotz equation we obtain

$$\Delta p +k^2 p=a_1\left[0\right]+a_2\left[0\right]=0$$
$$\implies \Delta p =-k^2 p$$

Hence, $p$ is also a solution of the Helmholtz equation.

Comment: So in my reasoning I should assume $k_{111}^2=k_{112}^2=...$?

Comment: Yes, it is not different because it is given by the differential equation, it is a specific constant. But note that $k$ is not the eigenvalue.